# Find a chain of functions to get a required output

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a following template:

```
template<class out_t, class in_t>
out_t my_cast(const in_t&) = delete;
```

And then several specializations:

```
template<>
B my_cast<B, A>(const A& a) { /* stuff */ }
template<>
X my_cast<X, A>(const A& a) { /* stuff */ }
template<>
C my_cast<C, B>(const B& b) { /* stuff */ }
template<>
C my_cast<C, X>(const X& x) { /* stuff */ }

template<>
V my_cast<V, A>(const A& a) { /* stuff */ }
template<>
Z my_cast<Z, V>(const V& v) { /* stuff */ }
```

If I wanted to cast from `A` to `Z`, I'd have to combine two casts like that: `auto z = my_cast<Z>(my_cast<V>(some_a))`;

This obviously is an example, I imagine cases where I'd have to go through tens of such casts, and coding this manually is clearly a no–go. Is there a way to automatically find those paths on compile time, so that `my_cast<Z>(some_a)` would be automatically resolved?

This can sadly lead to some ambiguities, like casting from `A` to `C`, which can be done in two ways: A→B→C, or A→X→C. In this case a compile error would satisfactory.

Comment: If a different syntax is good enough for you, you could define your casts as member functions: `some_type my_cast(std::integral_constant<int, i>) {...}`, where `i` is an incremental ID. Using tag as the parameter lets you use SFINAE to count all possible casts from a type, and then you can iterate over them at compile-time. After that you can recursively traverse the graph of casts looking for the needed type. I'll try to experiment with it and maybe will make an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done automatically. One level of automatic conversion is allowed but the compiler simply is not going to do more on its own.

Comment: Something tells me you underestimate template kung fu skills of SO residents. :) (it may requre a different syntax of conversion declarations, but still)

Comment: It seems doable with help of boost.hana, but it'd likely still be a nightmare.

…I shouldn't bother such old threads, should I?